Latest, Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-34-generic boot issue, black screen of death without any error message
I'm using mini pc device and I had installed ubuntu os latest as for April 27, 2024, on it. And just today April 28, early this morning the PC won't boot but on the advance boot option the Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-28-generic the PC boot normally, but the Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-34-generic can't boot on system, how to get rid of this latest update or how to set the boot default to Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-28-generic?


Please be clear & precise with details; you mention the latest Ubuntu, however mention the 6.5 kernel used by a prior release??  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is the latest release of Ubuntu and uses the 6.8 kernel, so what are you actually asking about? as the 6.5 kernel is used by two prior releases

"won't boot" is too vague to offer useful advice. There are many possible reasons why a computer OS won't boot. Please edit your question to clearly describe what does happen. Every screen, every word, every sound. Accurately reproduce all error messages completely. If the boot stops at a particular point consistently, then show us that point. Help us to help you.

I have the same problem, after the same update. Choosing recovery mode with the -34 version, it remains blocked on "loading initial ramdisk"

Thanks for this question. I had the same issue and without internet had to depend on a reinstall. 1 thing: how did you get the image you show. My LG Gram did not want to move from the BIOS logo.

Problem:
After an update, the system had two kernel versions in GRUB: one that was not functioning properly (6.5.0-34-generic) and one that was functioning properly (6.5.0-28-generic).
Goal:
Configure GRUB to automatically boot with the kernel version that functions properly (6.5.0-28-generic) and remove the kernel version that does not function (6.5.0-34-generic).
Steps and Commands:
Step 1: Check the installed kernel versions
To see which kernels are installed and how they are marked in the system, we used:
bash
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
This command lists all installed kernel versions, showing which are active (marked with ii) and which have been uninstalled but still retain configuration files (marked with rc).
Step 2: Modify the GRUB file
To change the default kernel on boot, we edited the GRUB configuration file:
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
In this file, we changed the line that says GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to:
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-28-generic"
This sets GRUB to automatically select the entry corresponding to the kernel 6.5.0-28-generic.
Step 3: Update GRUB
After saving the changes in the GRUB configuration file, we updated the GRUB configuration to apply the changes:
sudo update-grub
This command processes the changes and updates the GRUB menu as specified in the configuration file.
Step 4: Remove the problematic kernel
To completely remove the kernel that was causing problems, we used:
sudo apt remove --purge linux-image-6.5.0-34-generic linux-headers-6.5.0-34-generic
This command uninstalls the kernel 6.5.0-34-generic and its header files, cleaning up any residual configuration associated with them.
Step 5: Verify the boot
After making the changes, we recommended restarting the system to ensure that it boots with the correct kernel:
sudo reboot
After the reboot, we can verify that the active kernel is the desired one with:
uname -r
This command displays the version of the kernel that is currently in use, confirming that the changes to GRUB have been effective.
